# How do I specify table for foreign key in entity framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

All examples in tutorials I have read through only ever show 2 tables so I am confused on what to do in the following scenario.

Lets say we have 3 classes:

```
public class Product
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string skuA { get; set; }
        public string skuB { get; set; }

        public virtual SupplierA supplierA { get; set; }
        public virtual SupplierB supplierB { get; set; }
    }
public class Supplier A
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string sku { get; set; }
        public int price { get; set; }
    }
public class Supplier B
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string sku { get; set; }
        public int price { get; set; }
    }
```

If we need to join the appropriate product sku field then using the data annotation I have seen in tutorial it ends up looking like this:

```
[ForeignKey("sku")]
public string skuA { get; set; }
[ForeignKey("sku")]
public string skuB { get; set; }
```

How does entity framework know which foreign "sku" field we are annotating for? Does each foreign key have to be named differently?  I imagine this would become awkward if we had a hundred suppliers.

Are there some additional parameters or markup to handle this?  Any advice appreciated as I am finding this confusing.

Comment: just trying to understand, why are you not storing both suppliers under supplier? instead of having A, B...n

Comment: @Harry The table is for the suppliers products, not records of suppliers.  Fields may vary from supplier to supplier in order to line up with their catalogue data if that makes sense.  The sku represent an individual suppliers code for an item which may vary from supplier to supplier so the product table is the glue that joins them all together if you get what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

I misunderstood the purpose of the foreign key attribute.  It defines key on current class if it does not follow naming convention.

I was getting stuck as the error message I was getting stated I needed to use annotation or the fluent api but what it really meant was I had to use the fluent api as the relationship I wanted could not be specified with annotations.